# Maintain scroll position of a div inside Updatepanel when selecting index of Grid

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, gridview, updatepanel

[image]

I have this layout of my page. On my page there is an update panel. Inside that there is a textbox and a Div. Inside that div there is a grid. When I search a record in textbox,It selects the row of the grid and changes its color but the external div scrollbar doesnt scroll to that position. Can you let me know some jquery or c# code by which I can maintain the position.

Maintain Here doesn't mean that I need to keep the same position but to scroll automatically to the desired row.

**Gridview.SelectedRow.Focus(); Not Working**

Answer (score 0):

**On Text Changed Event I passed the selected Index of grid to javascript method.
and in Javascript I did this, and It worked.**

```
  function divScorllAdjust(index) {
        var div = document.getElementById("divGrid");
         div.scrollTop = index*20;
```

};